# Is there an alternative to type union which includes optional properties present only in some alternatives?

Tags: typescript

Given `type X = { id: number, x: number }` and `type Y = { id: string, y: number }`, is there a way to build `{ id: number | string, x?: number, y?: number }` out of them? And in the general case, to get all properties present in either type, but if a property is only present in one, it should be optional in the result.

I'm aware the usual solution is to use a standard union and discriminate on properties, for example,

```
const f = (xOrY: X | Y) => 'x' in xOrY ? /* xOrY is X here */ : /* xOrY is Y here */
```

but I'm specifically looking for a way to combine the types as requested.

Comment: So you're just assuming that a valid `Y` won't have an `x` property, and vice versa?  If so then someone could write a type like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wozvam) shows, that converts `X | Y` into your desired type, although it's a bit of juggling.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, this seems to give the desired result. Please do write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If TypeScript had sealed/closed/exact object types (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), then the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `Exact<X> | Exact<Y>`  is what you'd want to start with instead of `X | Y`.  Then you would just need to collapse it into a single type, such as using `Omit<Exact<X> | Exact<Y>, never>` to combine them (see [microsoft/TypeScript#28339](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28339) for an explanation of why [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) and [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) collapse unions instead of distributing over them).

But TypeScript doesn't have sealed types; a value of type `X` might have a `y` property, and a value of type `Y` might have an `x` property.  So the main goal here is to start with `X | Y` and produce a type in which the `X` member prohibits `y` and the `Y` member prohibits `X`.

Here's how one might do that:

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;

type Exactify<T, K extends PropertyKey = AllKeys<T>> =
    T extends unknown ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<K, keyof T>, never>> : never;
```

The `AllKeys<T>` utility type produces the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of keys from every member of the union `T`, using a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to split the union into members.

Then the `Exactify<T>` utility type converts the original union into a new one in which any key in `AllKeys<T>` which is not present in the current member of `T` is prohibited by [intesecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) the member of `T` with a [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) whose values for forbidden keys are of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).

(Note that because `T` is distributed into union members inside `Exactify`, it's not easy to write `AllKeys<T>` in a way that doesn't just give you the keys of one member.  I moved `AllKeys<T>` to be the [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to a `K` type parameter, so that `K` would always be `AllKeys<T>` for the whole type `T`. There are other ways to do it, but this works, so I'm leaving it.)

That produces

```
type Test = Exactify<X | Y>;
// type Test = (X & Partial<Record<"y", never>>) | (Y & Partial<Record<"x", never>>)
```

which is equivalent to `(X & {y?: never}) | (Y & {x?: never})`.  Given *that*, we can collapse to a single property via

```
type Optionalize<T> = Omit<Exactify<T>, never>;
```

And now we can test it:

```
type Z = Optionalize<X | Y>;
/* type Z = {
    id: string | number;
    x?: number | undefined;
    y?: number | undefined;
} */
```

That's what you wanted.

---

Note that we could inline those into a single utility type, as follows:

```
type Optionalize<T,
    K extends PropertyKey = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never
> = Omit<
  T extends unknown ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<K, keyof T>, never>> : never
, never>
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAFAlhRUkG8BQeSRSALgJ4zICCANjQNIRlQA8AKgHxIC8SbSEAB4kIwACbYArsADWwAPYB3YEgD8SGU3kAzPkgBcSYBABuEAE4BuQsXKUkAUUEISabWXYAaJPQHDREqjm8pTm5IxkPEi0DEysnFzcNsTE-EIi4lKyCspqegBkqCBhaCA0LABKmPLmYixO8DSSYhAs9N6aZDp8HN7GZuYcXIb9FtYpdsgA8jCu8qA0aABerZxRU2BoJPXO8K7uXtF0EfFDfaYWHNbJpBTIbNAkUU4ubh4AGkgAPkgAmlc3AD0gNu9geUCevAAFJ9Cihiq4ypVqrUWAAiMho84DIYASm+SChvyQcIRpXKVXgNTqaMEWKMF0GHFxBAIEzuSE+vBwSDQYhGkjAACMLN5BALhRYkABfG6TP5RHl8wwQ8xoYAAc28ZAlIvMMrlHIAWutZmh5mVlq1Pj9-uNiICAFSg5Am7k3FLKpCq9UagnAQV6+0pIiCVS6qU-aQtbTqiBiYMhsjhoyByNIaMQWPGBM3aVIR2AgiygjymZzBZWrw3XzpALYFDBULhJhRNL+TIZ7JKFTqTrdfgjRl4RJIDZbdh+DKBaRyHt5fikkpIynUnaNZqtdoaLS6TjYy7DBkDA+DUscrm4Xn81OS8xiiP62Xy4nc68qkhqzXax8G+VusczQtRYVhYG0-gBJ0XSQAD8E9G8fU1f00ysG4w1-KNxCzONcxSZMMK7GMcOsfNCzwIA)

Comment: First, thank you! Second, after I used this in my actual use-case, I see I missed one more desirable thing: can this be applied deeply? If `X` and `Y` have a property with the same name and different types, currently we simply get a union (as `id` in my example). But is it possible to get `Optionalize<X[key] | Y[key]>` there?

Comment: Maybe, but I don't know if I'm prepared to explore that here. If you can't figure out yourself how to make `Optionalize` recursive, maybe you should post a new question?

Comment: I tried to do it, but failed. The new question is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77960164/is-there-a-version-of-union-type-which-recursively-makes-properties-present-only.