# Is there a version of union type which recursively makes properties present only in one alternative optional?

Tags: typescript

This is a recursive version of [Is there an alternative to type union which includes optional properties present only in some alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77943067). The solution there gives

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;

type Exactify<T, K extends PropertyKey = AllKeys<T>> =
    T extends unknown ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<K, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type Test = Exactify<X | Y>;

type Optionalize<T> = Omit<Exactify<T>, never>;

type X = { id: number, x: number };
type Y = { id: string, y: number };

type Z = Optionalize<X | Y>;
/* type Z = {
    id: string | number;
    x?: number | undefined;
    y?: number | undefined;
} */
```

However, now let's say the shared properties like `id` in this example can themselves be object types. Then we get

```
type X1 = { shared: { x1: number }, x: number };
type Y1 = { shared: { y1: string }, y: number };

type Z1 = Optionalize<X1 | Y1>;
/* type Z1 = {
    shared: { x1: number } | { y1: string };
    x?: number | undefined;
    y?: number | undefined;
} */
```

I'd prefer `shared: { x1?: number, y1?: number }` and so on if *that* has any shared object type properties.

It is still safe to assume objects of these types don't have any extra properties (including one type's properties missing in the other).

A solution which only works up to some depth which is easy to adjust would be acceptable, but of course it's better if it works on any depth.

Comment: ① Please include the relevant definition of `Optionalize` here so this is a [mre] without needing to leave the page. ② Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WY20gw) meet your needs? If so, I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Sigh, I'm not a fan of situations where the scope changes in response to my suggestion. Maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NVe25w) works for you?

Comment: @jcalz I apologize, I was able to modify your approach myself: https://tsplay.dev/wR1M1W. Though I am not sure if that modification can break something else!

Comment: But what are we doing for this question here?

Comment: Please write up the original answer and I can revert the edit if you prefer.

Comment: Okay I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the original `Omit<Exactify<T>, never>` had the right property names, but it didn't recurse down into those properties and apply to each one.  We can fix that by taking `Omit<Exactify<T>, never>`, giving it an easy name to process like `U`, and then computing `{[K in keyof U]: Optionalize<U[K]>}`.  We also need to determine the base case, so we don't recurse forever. It only makes sense to recurse into objects (and maybe possibly `undefined` objects in the case of optional properties), so if `T` is assignable to `object | undefined` we recurse, otherwise `T` is a primitive type and we just return `T` itself.  Like this:

```
type Optionalize<T> =
    [T] extends [object | undefined] ? (
        Omit<Exactify<T>, never> extends infer U ? (
            { [K in keyof U]: Optionalize<U[K]> }
        ) : never
    ) : T;
```

Note that I wrote `[T] extends [object | undefined]` instead of the more obvious `T extends object | undefined` in order to avoid having it be a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) and splitting `T` into union members. We really do not want to split that union since the whole point is that we are merging the union.

Also note that I used [conditional type inference with `infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to copy `Omit<Exactify<T>, never>` into the type parameter `U`.  There are other ways to do this, but this works well enough.

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
type X1 = { shared: { x1: number }, x: number };
type Y1 = { shared: { y1: string }, y: number };

type Z1 = Optionalize<X1 | Y1>;
/* type Z1 = {
    shared: {
        x1?: number;
        y1?: string;
    };
    x?: number;
    y?: number;
} */
```

Looks good.  Do note that recursive conditional types like this tend to have bizarre edge cases, so you should thoroughly test against a representative set of inputs and be prepared to tweak or refactor the definition to deal with anything truly unacceptable.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIEEA2iDS1wGcA8AVAfLALyw6zQAeo0AdgCYawCu1A1tQPYDu1sA-LC3TsAZiVgAuWNWgA3aACcA3CAgxYAUXIBDAMagAlsPC4ANLBRlKNerAAK89jHkQ04IgmSvs+AoWCwAsQoqOgZmNi4eflIAMjstZ30tRCwAJWgddnlaLE0dREZaaCwUM0FwERI8M2k5eTwCSVqFZTAoOAB5SAN2amT9AC9i-CJ-QIBtHABdSxCbcfYAIwArDNBYAB8mOmhhfWlaGf4ACjHAwI6AW31QXO09Q2N8GtkFAmDrBn3hBVgAVT4sFO5xBgQA3rBxhZ9gIhKI-lNJF0en1EINin8oVMCABfM4ggCUEikr3k+KJkhwrTaagAGgBGdwQjAACwS0Fokgh5HpTUYl0WvxxZnIfIFQuUqjgAE1GcRmWz5ByubBwLzYBhQPJ9gBzWDC1ViwXyfWtKWwABactgyP0vX6QywDM2sFleGUAHoAFSwc1Wpn41nszmwMH48483hGlrhwJqqMarW65TnHEpwLkBPUfnG9MBcBZnMxnGwL0ekBAA)

Comment: "Also note that I used conditional type inference with infer to copy `Omit<Exactify<T>, never>` into the type parameter U." That's a very nice trick.